# [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition

Tags: vue.js

I am just starting a Vue site on GoDaddy, here is the link: http://picmymenu.com/
I keep getting a warning/error by simply importing a component. Here is my **app.js**:

```
Vue.component('nav-bar', 'navbar.vue')
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    template: '<li>This is a todo</li>'
})
var app = new Vue({1
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Pic-My-Menu!'
    }
});
```

Here is what I get:

```
You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition: navbar.vue

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.js:597
createComponent @ vue.js:4204
_createElement @ vue.js:4414
createElement @ vue.js:4351
vm._c @ vue.js:4483
(anonymous) @ VM4739:3
Vue._render @ vue.js:4535
updateComponent @ vue.js:2788
get @ vue.js:3140
Watcher @ vue.js:3129
mountComponent @ vue.js:2795
Vue.$mount @ vue.js:8527
Vue.$mount @ vue.js:10926
Vue._init @ vue.js:4627
Vue @ vue.js:4716
(anonymous) @ app.js:6
backend.js:1  vue-devtools  Detected Vue v2.5.17
```

in my app.js I defined a component called "todo-item" simply for testing purposes and it works just fine, however, inserting that same code in a file cases this warning/error.
Here is my component content "navbar.vue":

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">PiCMyMenu</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>
```

Any ideas?
**Thanks**

Comment: are you using Vue CLI (or Webpack)?

Comment: no I am not, it's hosted on godaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 import navbar from 'navbar.vue';
 Vue.component('nav-bar', navbar)
```

you are defining a component with a string but it need an object

Comment: thanks but I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". It is  referring to "import" I guess . its on the site if you wanna check

Comment: are you using any bundler?

Comment: no I am not, just pure html with links to bootstrap and vue  cdn

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use .vue files you should create your project with [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) (suggested) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), which compile it and create a "dist" folder with files you can deploy on GoDaddy.

Browser itself doesn't recognize import command.

Comment: but why can't I use

    Vue.component('nav-bar', 'js/components/navbar.vue')

Comment: because in this way you're assigning a string. Every time you need to load another file (module) you have to use import or require command (and a bundler which compiles those instructions)